# Count the number of same cell value in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I may need your advice on this to perform this on Powershell instead from Excel.
I have a sample CSV file as below.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sample.csv" | Group VM | select Name, @{N='Number';E={($_.Group|Measure-Object -Property Count -sum).Sum}}
```

[image]

```
VM,Group
USFS01,F
USPS01,P
EUDC01,A
EUPS01,P
JPDC01,A
JPPS01,P
```

And i wish to have the Output below and save the output with 5 rows blank between the input & output data, also generate barchart & piechart, all within the same spreadsheet.

```
Group   No.VM
-----   -----
A        2
F        1
P        3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We do not write ready to use code on request. What have you tried so far? Please show your code.  And ... [An image of code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Please show a sample code of what you have tried thus far!

Comment: I try the one-liner, seems not able to produce the output on right column.
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sample.csv" | Group VM | select Name, @{N='Number';E={($_.Group|Measure-Object -Property Count -sum).Sum}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inital command wasn't that bad, but

1. you chose the wrong property to group - it should be `Group` not `VM`
2. as all information needed is already contained use `Group-Object` with the `-NoElement` parameter

---

```
> Import-Csv -Path ".\sample.csv" | Group-Object Group -NoElement

Count Name
----- ----
    1 F
    3 P
    2 A
```

To have the exact property names and order you can use `Sort-Object`, `Select-Object`

```
Import-Csv -Path ".\sample.csv" | Group-Object Group -NoElement |
    Sort-Object Name | Select-Object @{n='Group';e={$_.Name}},@{n='No.VM';e={$_.Count}}

Group No.VM
----- -----
A         2
F         1
P         3
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. the latter one works.
How should i insert the output into the same CSV file with 3 rows blank in between them?

Comment: I'd choose a different output file, you started with the columns `VM,Group` and have now `Group,No.VM`. To save simply append ` | Export-Csv New.csv -NoTypeInformation` to the last line. Sorry but why insert blank lines in computed output?

Comment: Well i would actually want to combine both input & computed output into a chart, and convert to HTML format & send out in email. Do you think it's possible to do so?

Comment: That's beyont csv file, have a look at the ImportExcel module to do it in an excel file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sample.csv" 

$csv | Group-Object Group | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Group = $_.Name
        'No.VM' = ($_.Count)
    }
}
```

Below is a working example -

```
$csv = @'
VM,Group
USFS01,F
USPS01,P
EUDC01,A
EUPS01,P
JPDC01,A
JPPS01,P
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv | Group-Object Group | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Group = $_.Name
        'No.VM' = ($_.Count)
    }
}
```

**Output -**

```
No.VM Group
----- -----
    1 F
    3 P
    2 A
```

Comment: @Lixer: You CSV is not proper then. Either having some space or some data issue. Check what you are getting after using `convertfrom-csv`

Comment: use the delimiter parameter and hopefully it should work. `$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sample.csv" -Delimiter ";"`